# get all absolute file path of pdf files in java

Tags: java, file

I need to get all the `absolute file path` of the files with extension `.pdf`. I am using the code mentioned below, but I'm able to only get the absolute file path of only one file.

How can I modify the code to get all the absolute file paths ?

```
 public class FindFiles {

        String absoluteFilePath = "";
        String fileName;

         public String PdfFiles(String parentDirectory, String fileExtension) {

        FileFilter fileFilter = new FileFilter(fileExtension);

        File parentDir = new File(parentDirectory);

        // Put the names of all files ending with .pdf in a String array
        String[] listOfTextFiles = parentDir.list(fileFilter);

        if (listOfTextFiles.length == 0) {

            System.out.println("There are no files in this direcotry!");

        }

        for (String file : listOfTextFiles) {

            //construct the absolute file paths...
            absoluteFilePath = new StringBuffer(parentDirectory).append(File.separator).append(file).toString();

            fileName = file.toString();
        }
        return absoluteFilePath;
    }

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        FindFiles f = new FindFiles();
        f.PdfFiles("", "");
    }
}
```

Comment: Use a `StringBuilder` when you build `String`s using loops!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you are overrding `absoluteFilePath` every time in the loop;
try with

```
absoluteFilePath += new StringBuffer(parentDirectory).append(File.separator).append(file).toString();
```

Comment: A `StringBuilder` should be used here.

Answer (score 0):

Don't be bothered, use java.nio.file:

```
final Path dir = Paths.get(baseDir).toAbsolutePath();
final String filter = "*." + extension;

final List<Path> ret = new ArrayList<>();

try (
    final DirectoryStream<Path> dirstream 
        = Files.newDirectoryStream(dir, filter);
) {
    for (final Path entry: dirstream)
        ret.add(entry);
}

return ret;
```

If you use Java 8, it's even more simple.

Comment: I used `String Builder` as well as appended the `+` to my `String`  . I'm able to get all the `absolute file path`.

Comment: @Rajeev OK, but this solution is obsolete in 2015. Don't use `File` anymore.

Comment: Also, do you really want to limit yourself to one level? What if you have `base/foo.pdf` and `base/sub/bar.pdf`?

Comment: Well, I'm just creating `.pdf` and `.xls` files and storing them into a single `folder`. Then I am accessing the folder and sending the `files` as an attachment based on the `extension` the user specifies. For that I wanted the `absolute file path`.

Comment: And no I don't want to limit myself to one level. I need to understand your approach first to implement it. I am working on that too.

Comment: You may want to have a look at [this project](https://github.com/fge/java7-fs-more), it may have things of interest for you -- in particular it makes it very simple to archive a directory into a zip

Answer (score 0):

A more efficient solution for your problem can be given using classes in java.nio package.

E.g. For checking whether a file is a pdf file or not, use `Files.probeContentType(Path path)`.
Instead of writing loops to visit all directories and files inside these directories, use `Files.walkFileTree(Path start, FileVisitor<? super Path> visitor)`

Solution for your problem using these classes are

```
public class FindPdfFiles {
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException{
    final Path path = Paths.get("C:\\SearchDirectoryForPDF");
    Files.walkFileTree(path, new FindPdfFilesFilter());
}
}

class FindPdfFilesFilter extends  SimpleFileVisitor<Path> {
@Override
public FileVisitResult visitFile(Path path, BasicFileAttributes arg1)
        throws IOException {
    final String mimeTypeOfFile = Files.probeContentType(path);
    if(mimeTypeOfFile != null && !mimeTypeOfFile.isEmpty() && mimeTypeOfFile.toLowerCase().contains("pdf")) {
        System.out.println(path.toString());
    }
    return FileVisitResult.CONTINUE;
}
}
```